# How to make a matrix using a different matrix and the summation function

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I want to make a matrix T with t_ij = a_ij / sum a_ij for i from 1 to n. I know matrix A, it’s a 100x100 matrix.

This is what I’ve tried so far:

```
n2<-10000
mynumbers<-c(1,0)
myprobs<-c(0.2,0.8)
trials<-sample(mynumbers, n2, replace=TRUE, prob=myprobs)
matrixA<-matrix(trials, 100, 100)
matrixA
```

```
n=100
matrixT=matrix(0,100,100)
for(i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:n){
   matrixT[i,j]=matrixA[i,j]/sum(matrixA[1:n,j])
  }
}
matrixT
```

It doesn’t give any errors, but I have my doubts about it being correct, especially because my output has a lot of zeros. But this could be logical, I’m not sure. I’m especially struggling with the summation part of a_ij for i from 1 to n. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In R you can just write:

```
apply(matrixA, 2, function(x) x / sum(x))
```

to divide each column by column sum.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
prop.table(matrixA, 2)
```